# FullScreen iFrame using Javascript in iOS [Safari]

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, fullscreen

I set up full screen functions:

```
function setUpFullScreen() {
    document.cancelFullScreen = document.webkitCancelFullScreen || document.mozCancelFullScreen || document.cancelFullScreen;
    document.body.requestFullScreen = document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen || document.body.mozRequestFullScreen || document.body.requestFullScreen;
    document.onfullscreenchange = document.onfullscreenchange || document.onwebkitfullscreenchange || document.onmozfullscreenchange;
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', fullscreenChangeHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenChangeHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', fullscreenChangeHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', fullscreenChangeHandler, false);
    }
}
```

And toggle FullScreen using:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (isFullScreen()) {
        trace("Exiting fullscreen.");
        document.querySelector("svg#fullscreen title").textContent = "Enter fullscreen";
        document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else {
        trace("Entering fullscreen.");
        document.querySelector("svg#fullscreen title").textContent = "Exit fullscreen";
        document.body.requestFullScreen();
    }
}
```

Check is full screen:

```
function isFullScreen() {
    return !!(document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.isFullScreen);
}
```

Toggling fullscreen works on Chrome, Safari, Firefox (on Desktop) and also Chrome on Android. However, NOT WORKING on Safari and Chrome. I see the following error on safari:

```
TypeError: document.body.requestFullScreen is not a function. (In 'document.body.requestFullScreen()', 'document.body.requestFullScreen' is undefined)
```

How to accomplish fullscreen functionality on iOS using javascript?

FYI: My code is an adaptation of https://appr.tc/ 
https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc/blob/master/src/web_app/js/appcontroller.js

Comment: How is `setUpFullScreen` function run/executed?

Comment: @leo.fcx setUpFullScreen is invoked after loading the iframe. These methods are part of the page loaded in the iframe.

Comment: Does that mean using `window.onload` or something similar?

Comment: @leo.fcx FYI: My code is an adaptation of https://appr.tc/ https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc/blob/master/src/web_app/js/appcontroller.js

Comment: That does not answer my question, even if it is just an adaptation. Did you try using `window.onload`?

Comment: I see, it's not done at the window onload. You suggest that I should setUpFullScreen on window load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

in the HTML file worked for me.